# Angular safe navigation operator in property binding

Tags: html, angular

Why is the safe navigation operator in Angular(4) not working with property binding? The following html code produces an error (as it will try to `GET` http://localhost:4200/null)

```
    <img [src]="(image | async)?.url" />
```

But then when I change it to the following expression, everything works fine.

```
    <img src="{{(image | async)?.url}}" />
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two excerpts? They look like the same thing to me

Comment: Fixed that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Property binding

```
<img [src]="(image | async)?.url" />
```

produces assigning:

```
img.src = null;
```

2) Interpolation

```
<img src="{{(image | async)?.url}}" />
```

I would call it **stringified property binding**

We could expect the result `img.src = 'null';` since `null` is `'null'` after converting to string but to stringify angular executes the following code:

```
'' + _toStringWithNull(null) + ''
                       ^^^^
                    value from Pipe
```

where `_toStringWithNull` function looks like:

```
function _toStringWithNull(v) {
    return v != null ? v.toString() : '';
}
```

so the result will be:

```
img.src = '';
```

3) Attribute binding

Angular won't add attribute if value is `null`

---

Now just open chrome dev tools with empty `img` tag and try changing its src property

```
$0.src = null
```

and then

```
$0.src = ''
```

[image]

Here is what i see for all aforementioned cases:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before `image` value becomes available, it actually is `null`. 
`{{}}` is for string interpolation and it is like if you add `src="null"`.

Only when the async call (Promise, Observable) returns a value, it changes from `null` to an actual value.

Use attribute binding instead

```
<img [attr.src]="(image | async)?.url" />
```

This way the `src` attribute will only be added when the value is `!= null` and therefore the browser won't try to fetch from the url `'null'`

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question, it's the property binding that gives me issues and the text interpolation that actually works

Comment: You can try my updated answer. I don't know why the `src` property handles `null` like that.

Comment: That actually worked, any idea what's the difference and why this doesn't produce the error?

Comment: The difference is that ’[src]="..."` is property binding that passes the raw value. `src="{{...}}"` is property binding that passes the stringified value and `[attr.src]="..."` is attribute binding which always stringifies the value, but `null` causes Angular to remove the attribute and only add it when the value becomes `!= null` (as I initially wrongly claimed for property binding).